# Weird error with the Keyboard module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import keyboard

hotkeyUp = "1"
hotkeyDown = "2"

def Increase():
    print("Function has been executed with hotkey r")

keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkeyDown,Increase())
```

That is the test code I made outside my original program I wanted to implement hotkeys, but it wont even run, as it says "Module 'keyboard' has no 'add_hotkey' memberpylint(no-member)" even tho add_hotkey is definitely a function of keyboard, I looked in my libraries itself manually, and I went into a command prompt, opened python interpreter, and manually did the code and the print function(though now im doing it again, and now its giving me the "Module 'keyboard' has no 'add_hotkey' memberpylint(no-member)" error FOR EVEN IMPORTING THE KEYBOARD (import keyboard)
What is going on??? I look it up, google, stack overflow, NO ONE has this issue, yet why am i, this should be working.

Comment: There is no `keyboard` module in the stdlib. Is it some 3rd-party library?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ its this, and I uninstalled and reinstalled (pip install keyboard) and it still has the same error

Comment: The whole `memberpylint` business sounds like there might be an issue with your IDE. Does your script run from the command line?

Comment: I tried through command line interpreter, as I said through command prompt, putting in as I would normally, and as SOON as i type/enter import keyboard, it does the add_hotkey error even tho the ONLY thing in command line is import keyboard which errors, If you mean running the py file from command prompt, I did that as well, and same results

Comment: Is your file called `keyboard.py` by any chance?

Comment: :O it is for a long time and only reason i did that is as a test "workbench" area separate from rest of my programs, to test diff things out, and keyboard cuz it all tied back to trying to get user input without user clicking enter. Now you brought it up, it does make sense and i have used that functionality, importing key.py into another program for security. Thanks for the help!! That issue was annoying me so much XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above extremely helpful comment, issue was due to name conflicts, I named my test python file the same as one I was trying to work with its library and IDE was getting confused since it was all in the same directory. Lesson to Learn, don't name files same as what you would ever import from pip or std libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import keyboard

hotkeyUp = "1"
hotkeyDown = "2"

def Increase():
    print("Function has been executed with hotkey r")

keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkeyDown,Increase)
```

Comment: Can you add a sentence explaining what you changed from OP's code and how you expect it to help?